# Как поменять режим через checkbox

Tags: javascript

Я хочу когда была галочка на checkbox я мог вести мячик, а когда нет галочки не мог.

```js
let ball = document.querySelector('.ball');
let check = document.querySelector('.check');

check.addEventListener('change', function (  ) {

    if (check.checked === true) {
        ball.onmousedown = function(event) { // (1) отследить нажатие
            ball.style.transitionProperty = '';
            // (2) подготовить к перемещению:
            // разместить поверх остального содержимого и в абсолютных координатах
            ball.style.position = 'absolute';
            ball.style.zIndex = 1000;
            // переместим в body, чтобы мяч был точно не внутри position:relative
            document.body.append( ball );
            // и установим абсолютно спозиционированный мяч под курсор

            moveAt( event.pageX , event.pageY );

            // передвинуть мяч под координаты курсора
            // и сдвинуть на половину ширины/высоты для центрирования
            function moveAt( pageX , pageY ) {
                ball.style.left = pageX - ball.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px';
                ball.style.top = pageY - ball.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
            }

            function onMouseMove( event ) {
                moveAt( event.pageX , event.pageY );
            }

            // (3) перемещать по экрану
            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove' , onMouseMove );

            // (4) положить мяч, удалить более ненужные обработчики событий
            ball.onmouseup = function () {
                document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove' , onMouseMove );
                ball.onmouseup = null;
                ball.ondragstart = function () {
                    return false;
                };
            };


        };
        };
});
```

```css
.ground {
    position: relative;
    width: 700px; height: 700px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, rgb(37, 53, 222), rgb(64, 55, 203), rgb(91, 57, 185), rgb(119, 58, 166), rgb(146, 60, 148), rgb(173, 62, 129), rgb(174, 58, 143), rgb(174, 54, 157), rgb(175, 50, 171), rgb(176, 46, 184), rgb(176, 42, 198), rgb(177, 38, 212));
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    border: 3px cornflowerblue solid;
}

.ball {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
    transition: none 1s ease-out;
    transition-property: background-color;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, rgb(115, 240, 19), rgb(138, 222, 22), rgb(161, 204, 24), rgb(184, 187, 27), rgb(207, 169, 29), rgb(230, 151, 32), rgb(230, 129, 30), rgb(231, 107, 27), rgb(231, 85, 25), rgb(231, 62, 23), rgb(232, 40, 20), rgb(232, 18, 18));
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="lol"><input type="checkbox" class="check"> <span><sup>*</sup> Режим свободного ведения (Вы можете водить круг куда вам хочется )</span></div> <br>
        <div class="ground">
            <div class="ball" id="ball">

            </div>
        </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перенесите просто проверку на поле `check` в функцию нажатия кнопки. 
Пример:

```js
    let ball = document.querySelector('.ball');
    let check = document.querySelector('.check');

    check.addEventListener('change', function (  ) {
        ball.onmousedown = function(event) { // (1) отследить нажатие
            if (check.checked === true) {
                ball.style.transitionProperty = '';
                // (2) подготовить к перемещению:
                // разместить поверх остального содержимого и в абсолютных координатах
                ball.style.position = 'absolute';
                ball.style.zIndex = 1000;
                // переместим в body, чтобы мяч был точно не внутри position:relative
                document.body.append(ball);
                // и установим абсолютно спозиционированный мяч под курсор

                moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

                // передвинуть мяч под координаты курсора
                // и сдвинуть на половину ширины/высоты для центрирования
                function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
                    ball.style.left = pageX - ball.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px';
                    ball.style.top = pageY - ball.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
                }

                function onMouseMove(event) {
                    moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);
                }

                // (3) перемещать по экрану
                document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

                // (4) положить мяч, удалить более ненужные обработчики событий
                ball.onmouseup = function () {
                    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
                    ball.onmouseup = null;
                    ball.ondragstart = function () {
                        return false;
                    };
                };

            }
        };
    });
```

```css
    .ground {
        position: relative;
        width: 700px; height: 700px;
        margin: 20px 0;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, rgb(37, 53, 222), rgb(64, 55, 203), rgb(91, 57, 185), rgb(119, 58, 166), rgb(146, 60, 148), rgb(173, 62, 129), rgb(174, 58, 143), rgb(174, 54, 157), rgb(175, 50, 171), rgb(176, 46, 184), rgb(176, 42, 198), rgb(177, 38, 212));
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
        border: 3px cornflowerblue solid;
    }

    .ball {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px; height: 100px;
        transition: none 1s ease-out;
        transition-property: background-color;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, rgb(115, 240, 19), rgb(138, 222, 22), rgb(161, 204, 24), rgb(184, 187, 27), rgb(207, 169, 29), rgb(230, 151, 32), rgb(230, 129, 30), rgb(231, 107, 27), rgb(231, 85, 25), rgb(231, 62, 23), rgb(232, 40, 20), rgb(232, 18, 18));
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="lol"><input type="checkbox" class="check"> <span><sup>*</sup> Режим свободного ведения (Вы можете водить круг куда вам хочется )</span></div> <br>
    <div class="ground">
        <div class="ball" id="ball">

        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто добавить отдельную переменную, по умолчанию равную false. При чеке\анчеке чекбокса изменять эту переменную на противоположную (true\false), а строчку

```
if (check.checked === true) {
```

заменить на

```
if (названиеПеременной === true) {
```

Это, наверное, будет самым простым выходом, если не охота разбираться с замыканием и всякими другими штуками.